# Select $variable and column from table?

Tags: php, mysql, select, post, foreach

How can I SELECT Both $ss & extra_column from table?
Here's my code , and Im getting an error on SELECT

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
$ss="".$selected.", extra_col";
$options=mysql_query("SELECT $ss FROM table");
 while($arl=mysql_fetch_array($options)) {
  echo $arl['col1']; //echo if selected
  echo $arl['col2']; //echo if selected
  echo $arl['col3']; //echo if selected
  echo $arl['extra_col']; //echo anyway its the extra_col
  }


  }else{
 echo "<b>Please Tick Atleast One Option.</b>";
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a very high risk of sql injection, you really should use a white-list to make sure that only the columns that exist can get added to your string; you should validate all `$_POST` values.

That being said, you are using quotes where you shouldn't and if you need quotes for special column names, you should use backticks:

```
$ss="`".$selected."`,";
$options=mysql_query("SELECT $ss extra_col FROM table");
```

And from what I can see from your code, you probably want to build your `$ss` string in the loop and run your query after it.

Something like:

```
$ss = '';
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
  $ss .= "`".$selected."`, ";
}
$options=mysql_query("SELECT $ss extra_col FROM table");
```

Comment: hmph , well I really don't mind the injection part its not a login form its a search form using tags and the $_post checklist are tag words . Ill edit the question with the full code if thats ok ^^

Comment: @MicaButu It does not matter what it is for, what if someone posts for example `id\`, * FROM users; --`? That would send all information of your `users` table to the attacker.

Comment: em there are no users in the table at all not even in this database so I don't worry when theres nothing to attack @jeroen I edited the question is the picture a little more clear now?

Comment: @MicaButu You are missing the point, this is just an example, I could also query for the mysql system tables. And the code at the end of my answer seems to be exactly what you need. Apart from the sql injection ;-)

Comment: can you help me with one more thing please ^^ the echo's that Ive displayed in the updated question they give error ... that are Undentified Index Any idea?

Comment: @MicaButu `mysql_fetch_array` gets you a 0-indexed array, you probably want `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Also note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is absolutely unclear. But just to start you should fix your query string creation to something like:

```
$ss="`".$selected."`, extra_col";
$options=mysql_query("SELECT $ss FROM table");
```

Comment: Well what your answer will have will be $ss ="col1, extra_col, col2, extra_col, col3, extra_col";
Can you see why :?

Comment: No I can't see, your loop is for each value. so it is not `$ss.=` it is just `$ss=` so it will never has value `"col1, extra_col, col2, extra_col, col3, extra_col"`

Comment: Um ... but its foreach which does loop it